# how i can store geolocation Longitude and latitude values in database with method of <input>

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, laravel

Html code

```
<html>

<body>

<p>Click the button to get your coordinates.</p>

<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>

var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;

}
</script>
<input  name="x.innerHTML" id="x.innerHTML" required value="">
</body>
</html>
```

Latitude: 31.554606099999994     Longitude: 74.3571581
I have to store these values in Database by using input method on submit.

Comment: you'll need a `<form>` and server side code to accept the submission of your data ... by the way ... what does `name="x.innerHTML" id="x.innerHTML"` on the input hope to achieve?

Comment: is it possible that if x.innerHTML storing longitude and latitude values and we store in input field as hidden and same value store on submit button>?

Comment: there is no submit button

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>

<body>

<p>Click the button to get your coordinates.</p>

<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
<form action="insert_in_db.php">
    <input name="geoData" id="inputId" required value="">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script>

var x = document.getElementById("inputId");

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else { 
        x.value = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {
    x.value = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;

}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```